# Current thinking on the reasons for 3 particle generations

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, standard-model

A question was asked a number of times on this forum, mostly in 2011-2013, of the theoretical reasons for exactly 3 generations of elementary particles. The answers mentioned that certain observed processes could not happen with less than 3 generations, but at that time almost all sources (except [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1006.3114)) agreed that the specific reasons for exactly 3 generations were unknown.

My question is if there have been any theoretical developments lately suggesting a theoretical reason fo the number of generations being exactly 3.

The question is about potential recent developments, please do not mark it as a "duplicate" of questions asked years ago.

Comment: A complete answer to this question would be "No". Or rather, theories may exist, but there is no confirmation as of yet for any beyond the SM theory.

Comment: If you have credible reason to believe there are new answers to old questions, the correct way to entice users to post these answers is to offer a bounty with the "Current answers are outdated" reason, not to duplicate the question.

Comment: @ACuriousMind With all due respect, this makes no sense. I have no reason to believe in anything, I am *asking*, not *answering*. The earlier question is not a duplicate, as there is a logical difference between *only 3* (a limitation) and *exactly 3* (a reflection of a fundamental symmetry). This censorship is unreasonable and unnecessary.